# Horizontally center TextView inside ImageView

Tags: android

How to horizontally center TextView inside ImageView?
Currently is positioned in the lower right corner of ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/img" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the `TextView` to fit always the `ImageView` size independently where it is positioned on the `RelativeLayout` you should try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/img" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="hsjsdjhf"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you help me, I would like the text at the bottom in the center, I just cant figure out the xml!?

Comment: I guess you just need to remove the  following from the TextView:
android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView"

And change the following
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

Try `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and set `gravity="center"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/img" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/texts" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you help me, I would like the text at the bottom in the center, I just cant figure out the xml!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
To align the elements on the top of each other you should use `frame layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/img" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@drawable/img" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="hsjsdjhf"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```